# Racket macro to stringify all but s-expressions

Tags: macros, racket

I am trying to figure out how to create a racket macro that will simply convert to a string all contents except for s-expressions which it will leave alone.

I got as far as figuring out how to stringify everything

```
  #+begin_src racket
    (define-syntax (stringify-all stx)
      (syntax-case stx ()
        [(_ args ...)
         #'(begin
             (~s 'args)
             ...)]))

    (stringify-all one 2 (add1 2))
  #+end_src

  #+RESULTS:
  : "one"
  : "2"
  : "(add1 2)"
```

But have no clue how to test whether something is an s-expression or not.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"s-expression" is syntax list/pair, so you can pattern match for `()` and `(a . b)`, like this:

```
#lang racket

(require (for-syntax (only-in racket/format ~s)))

(define-for-syntax (compute stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [() #'null]
    [(a . b) #`(cons #,(compute #'a) #,(compute #'b))]
    [_ (~s (syntax-e stx))]))

(define-syntax (stringify-all stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ args ...)
     #`(begin #,@(map compute (syntax->list #'(args ...))))]))

(stringify-all one 2 (add1 2))

;; "one"
;; "2"
;; '("add1" "2")
```

Comment: Ah thanks! I wanted to just evaluate nested s-expressions, but I think I can figure that bit out. This is great, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If we use the usual definition of the `atom?` procedure as reference:

```
(defne (atom? exp)
  (and (not (null? exp))
       (not (pair? exp))))
```

Then we could define an s-expression predicate as:

```
(define (s-exp? exp)
  (or (null? exp)
      (pair? exp)))
```

And of course, you'd need to apply this recursively to each of the elements of an s-expression.